# What's wrong with my semi complete Sudoku solver?

Tags: php, algorithm, puzzle

I'm trying to practice algorithm questions and I'm currently attempting a sudoku solver, please bare in mind that it isn't currently finished! I haven't added backtracking when there is more than one option that the cell could be, but my issue currently is that my if statement to check if there is only one possible answer the cell could be is failing, as the semi filled sudoku its returning is wrong.

Also feel free to give me tips on how to speed things up etc.

```
    function sudoku(array $puzzle): array
    {
        // Return the solved puzzle as a 9 × 9 grid
        $data = [];
        for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
            for ($a = 0; $a < 8; $a++) {
                if ($puzzle[$i][$a] == 0) {
                    $horizontal_missing = getHorizontalNumbers($puzzle[$i]);
                    $vertical_missing = getVerticalNumbers($puzzle, $a);
                    $square_missing = getSquareNumbers($puzzle, $i, $a);
                    $intersect = array_intersect($horizontal_missing,$vertical_missing,$square_missing);
                    if (count($intersect) == 1) {
                        sort($intersect);
                        $puzzle[$i][$a] = $intersect[0];
                        $i = 0;
                        $a = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return $puzzle;
    }

    function getSquareNumbers($p, $row, $col)
    {
        $sectors = [1 => [0, 2], 2 => [3, 5], 3 => [6, 8]];
        $across = getSector($sectors, $row);
        $down = getSector($sectors, $col);
        switch (($across * $down)) {
            case 1:
                $row = [
                    $p[0][0], $p[0][1], $p[0][2],
                    $p[1][0], $p[1][1], $p[1][2],
                    $p[2][0], $p[2][1], $p[2][2]
                ];
                break;
            case 2:
                $row = [
                    $p[0][3], $p[0][4], $p[0][5],
                    $p[1][3], $p[1][4], $p[1][5],
                    $p[2][3], $p[2][4], $p[2][5]
                ];
                break;
            case 3:
                $row = [
                    $p[0][6], $p[0][7], $p[0][8],
                    $p[1][6], $p[1][7], $p[1][8],
                    $p[2][6], $p[2][7], $p[2][8]
                ];
                break;
            case 4:
                $row = [
                    $p[3][0], $p[3][1], $p[3][2],
                    $p[4][0], $p[4][1], $p[4][2],
                    $p[5][0], $p[5][1], $p[5][2]
                ];
                break;
            case 5:
                $row = [
                    $p[3][3], $p[3][4], $p[3][5],
                    $p[4][3], $p[4][4], $p[4][5],
                    $p[5][3], $p[5][4], $p[5][5]
                ];
                break;
            case 6:
                $row = [
                    $p[3][6], $p[3][7], $p[3][8],
                    $p[4][6], $p[4][7], $p[4][8],
                    $p[5][6], $p[5][7], $p[5][8]
                ];
                break;
            case 7:
                $row = [
                    $p[6][0], $p[6][1], $p[6][2],
                    $p[7][0], $p[7][1], $p[7][2],
                    $p[8][0], $p[8][1], $p[8][2]
                ];
                break;
            case 8:
                $row = [
                    $p[6][3], $p[6][4], $p[6][5],
                    $p[7][3], $p[7][4], $p[7][5],
                    $p[8][3], $p[8][4], $p[8][5]
                ];
                break;
            case 9:
                $row = [
                    $p[6][6], $p[6][7], $p[6][8],
                    $p[7][6], $p[7][7], $p[7][8],
                    $p[8][6], $p[8][7], $p[8][8]
                ];
                break;
        }
        return getHorizontalNumbers($row);
    }

    function getSector($sectors, $num)
    {
        if (($sectors[1][0] <= $num) && ($num <= $sectors[1][1])) {
            return 1;
        } else if (($sectors[2][0] <= $num) && ($num <= $sectors[2][1])) {
            return 2;
        } else if (($sectors[3][0] <= $num) && ($num <= $sectors[3][1])) {
            return 3;
        }
    }

    function getHorizontalNumbers($row)
    {
        $missing = [];
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++) {
            if (!in_array($i, $row)) {
                $missing[] = $i;
            }
        }
        return $missing;
    }

    function getVerticalNumbers($puzzle, $col)
    {
        $row = [
            $puzzle[0][$col],
            $puzzle[1][$col],
            $puzzle[2][$col],
            $puzzle[3][$col],
            $puzzle[4][$col],
            $puzzle[5][$col],
            $puzzle[6][$col],
            $puzzle[7][$col],
            $puzzle[8][$col]
        ];
        return getHorizontalNumbers($row);
    }

    $data = sudoku([
        [5, 3, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [6, 0, 0, 1, 9, 5, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 9, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0],
        [8, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 3],
        [4, 0, 0, 8, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1],
        [7, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6],
        [0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 8, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 9, 0, 0, 5],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 7, 9]
    ]);
    $string = '';
    $count = 0;
    foreach($data as $key => $row){
        foreach($row as $cell){
            $count++;
            if ($count == 9){
                $string.= $cell.", \n";
                $count = 0;
            } else {
                $string.= $cell.", ";
            }
        }
    }
    echo nl2br($string);
```

Surely if I'm only inputting numbers where there is only ONE common denominator between vertical line, horizontal line and the square there shouldn't be any errors in the SEMI filled Sudoku so far, yet there is? What am I missing? My brain can't compute lol.

Comment: Please don't share all the code. This is way too much unnecessary informations. Concentrate on the main problem and only share the code which could cause it.

Comment: I can't find where its tripping up hence my question.

Comment: Does the program break at any point? If so use a debugger to isolate the problem. Do you have weird output or just don't know why it's not working? Always use a debugger to isolate the problem first or we can't really help you

Comment: Your question si too broad, you should try to narrow your question on a specific token to have a chance to have a valuable answer. The bright side of this process, is that often you will find the error by yourself. For example: what do you intend when you write that the procedure to find a singe value is failing? Any example?

Comment: ... use a debugger or isolate the different functions and unit tests  them to assert they are behaving well (and that they will continue to do so).

Comment: @Eineki Unit tests might be a bit overkill for the purpose of the program.. :D

Comment: It outputs a semi complete sudoku, doesn't error at any point. Currently my assumption is that if Im only changing a cell if there is only ONE possible common denominator, which should in theory return only correct changes thus far, however the in the result I can clearly see one line that conflicts with another which is what is stumping me. I will go back and try debugging like suggested thanks.

Comment: then you can write down the unfinished sudoku, and feed it to the function you think is misbehaving to see what happen in isolation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `getSquareNumbers` you assume that `$across * $down` gives unique values, but that is not true:

For example 1*3 is 3, but also 3*1 is 1. Furthermore, there is no case where the product is 5, 7 or 8. So in many cases your code is looking at the wrong square area.

You can avoid a lot of code (duplication) by just using the modulo operator and slice the rows of the grid at given indices.

Secondly, you seem to swap the meaning of `$down` and `$across`. The first should be about *rows* and the second about *columns*, and the code does relates them differently.

Here is the suggested fix for that function:

```
    function getSquareNumbers($p, $row, $col)
    {
        $down = $row - $row % 3; // This will be 0, 3 or 6
        $across = $col - $col % 3; // This will be 0, 3 or 6
        $row = [...array_slice($p[$down+0], $across, $across + 3),
                ...array_slice($p[$down+1], $across, $across + 3),
                ...array_slice($p[$down+2], $across, $across + 3)];
        return getHorizontalNumbers($row);
    }
```

Now your grid will be filled more... still leaving some zeroes, but those zeroes really represent cells that cannot be solved as there is no value that can be put there without violating one of the rules. So this is where you need to implement backtracking to continue the process in an alternative direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
function test_sectors($puzzle=null) {                                                       
    if (!$puzzle) {                                                                         
        $puzzle = [                                                                         
            [1,1,1, 2,2,2, 3,3,3],                                                          
            [1,1,1, 2,2,2, 3,3,3],                                                          
            [1,1,1, 2,2,2, 3,3,3],                                                          
            [4,4,4, 5,5,5, 6,6,6],                                                          
            [4,4,4, 5,5,5, 6,6,6],                                                          
            [4,4,4, 5,5,5, 6,6,6],                                                          
            [7,7,7, 8,8,8, 9,9,9],                                                          
            [7,7,7, 8,8,8, 9,9,9],                                                          
            [7,7,7, 8,8,8, 9,9,9]                                                           
        ];                                                                                  
    }                                                                                       
                                                                                        
    for ($i=0; $i<9; $i++) {                                                                
        for ($j=0; $j<9; $j++) {
            $expected = $puzzle[$i][$j];
            $sector = getSquareNumbers($puzzle, $i, $j);                                                          
            if ($sector[0] == $expected) {
                echo ".";
            } else {
                echo "F (got sector {$sector[0]} expected {$expected} at coord [{$i}][{$j}])\n";
            };
        }                                                                                   
    }                                                                                       
}                                                                                           
                                                                                        
test_sectors();
```

I did this function (I do not have a php at hand now) to test the behaviour of your `getSquareNumbers` function that seems odd to me. You can use it to see if the correct square is selected for every possible coordinate, you can automate it too (but it is up to you).

Edit:
Rewritten a la unit test fashion!